# How to install and connect MathJax to Jupyter notebook 5.2.1?

Tags: latex, anaconda, jupyter

I have [Jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) from the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/).

I recently updated Jupyter with the command `conda update notebook`.

I am interested to know how to use the LaTex format with Jupyter.

Apparently, [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is needed for that. How can I install MathJax and connect it with the Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Have a look at https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/install/install.html#mathjax

Answer (score 2):

From [Jupyter Notebook's Official documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.html):

"The Markdown parser included in the Jupyter Notebook is MathJax-aware. This means that you can freely mix in mathematical expressions using the MathJax subset of Tex and LaTeX. Some examples from the MathJax site are reproduced below, as well as the Markdown+TeX source"

For examples of how to use MathJax for your Jupyter Notebook equations. These sites can be very helpful:

- [mathjax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
- [Latex commands available in MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm)